# Circom circuit compilation error : Type NQ can not be converted to QEX

Tags: javascript, node.js, cryptography

I am currently working with zero-knowledge proofs, and as such I use Node.js with its circom and snarkjs packages.

I am trying to run `circom circuit.circom --r1cs --wasm --sym` with the following circuit :

```
template Accum() {
    signal private input a;
    signal private input b;
    signal input n;
    signal output c;

    c <== (a**b) % n;
}

component main = Accum();
```

but I get the error :

```
Error: Type NQ can not be converted to QEX
    at LCAlgebra.toQEX (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/circom/src/lcalgebra.js:433:19)
    at execConstrain (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/circom/src/construction_phase.js:931:37)
    at execSignalAssignConstrain (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/circom/src/construction_phase.js:943:5)
    at exec (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/circom/src/construction_phase.js:110:20)
    at execBlock (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/circom/src/construction_phase.js:534:9)
    at instantiateComponent (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/circom/src/construction_phase.js:521:9)
    at execInstantiateComponet (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/circom/src/construction_phase.js:463:9)
    at execAssignement (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/circom/src/construction_phase.js:364:31)
    at exec (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/circom/src/construction_phase.js:106:20)
    at execBlock (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/circom/src/construction_phase.js:534:9)
Type NQ can not be converted to QEX
```

My understanding is that the error is linked to my use of exponentiation and moduli, but I could not correct it.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You will have to implement [fast modular exponentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation#Right-to-left_binary_method) as a separate template or function. The page also provides you with a pseudocode you can implement.